# Random pulse generator issue

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm new in Simulink and i'm trying to create a random pulse generator. Pulses have amplitude (1 ) and width (6 nano sec). The signal has to be periodic (T=30 nano sec). how can i do it? I apprecitate any help. 
Thanks.

Comment: If neither the amplitude, width, or period is random, then what is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The amplitude takes the  values 0 or 1 randomly

Comment: So the decision to rise or not is made at exact intervals of 30 nanoseconds?  If the decision is made to rise then it rises to 1 for exactly 6 nanoseconds and is then 0 for the next 24 nanoseconds before a new decision is made?  If a decision not to rise is made then the signal is 0 for 30 nanoseconds before a new decision is made?